# Cant install watir-webdriver on windows 7

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, ruby-development-kit

Hello i'am trying to install watir-webdriver on Windows 7 with Ruby 1.9.3 and installation hang on this:

building native extensions. This could take a while...

and i'am waiting
and i'am waiting
and i'am waiting

and nothing goes forward. Can you give me what i'am doing wrong.

Previously i'am installed Ruby 1.9.3, updated gems, installed devkit.

Thanks for future help.

Comment: Is watir webdriver failing, or some other gem like ffi?

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the instructions?

https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md

Try installation with verbose output and let us know what you get:

```
gem install watir-webdriver -V
```

Comment: URL is broken, please update to https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md

Answer (score 1):

I had to change my c:\ruby193\bin\gem.bat in the following to get the devkit working for native extensions

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
ECHO.This version of Ruby has not been built with support for Windows 95/98/Me.
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
SET HTTP_PROXY=server.domain.com:9999
SET RI_DEVKIT=c:\devkit\
SET PATH=%RI_DEVKIT%bin;%RI_DEVKIT%mingw\bin;%PATH%
@"%~dp0ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

Comment: This got me going on the right path. For me, I had to 1) Open a DOS prompt (not a msys shell or anything). 2) Run C:\Ruby192\devkitvars.bat
3) gem install watir